# typescript jasmin mock/spy public property

Tags: angular, typescript, angularjs-components

```
export class Thing {
    public thingForm: any;
    public loading: boolean = true;
    constructor{...}
    public $onInit(): void {...}
    public submit = (): void => {
        ...
        this.doValidation();
    }
    private doValidation = (): void => {
        this.loading = false;
        this.thingForm.name.$setValidity('name', false);
    }
}

it('should fail validation', () => {
    ctrl = getController();
    ctrl.submit();
    $scope.apply();
    expect(ctrl.loading).toBeFalsy();
});
```

Ok, so I am trying to write a test for this scenario but failing miserably. Tried doing jasmin.createSpy/createSpyObject, spy on property and etc. but nothing seems to work. I am keep getting error showing:

`undefined is not an object (evaluating _this.thingForm.name)...`

Can someone please tell me how do I mock this thing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You do not show what method you are currently trying to validate, so it's difficult to answer your question, because your question is unclear.  Tell us *what* you are trying to prove in your test, and we can show you how to prove that.

Comment: Updated the code. Didn't want to cut n paste all of it...just the gist. I am trying to test the submit method and assert the loading value.

Comment: The error you listed says that `this.thingForm` does not exist.  Perhaps you have to create it / mock it for your tests?  This might be like saying `ctrl.thingForm = someMockForm;` or `ctrl.thingForm = theActualFormItShouldBe;`

Comment: Yeah I was able to mock it finally. Thanks!